# how to put a logo in a jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put a logo in a jquery dialog box at left side of the title window(e.g mozilla firefox logo in FF). How can it be achieved?

Comment: `position` and `z-index`. That's all I can say without you providing more info. You want this on every dialog or just one? What did you try? What happened when you tried it? Did you try anything at all?

Comment: @Madmartigan, i like how you answered the question with 3 more lol

Comment: @corroded: This is a comment, not an answer lol. And it was **4** questions ;)

Comment: yeah well it is still an answer lol..or better yet..a "reply". oh yeah must learn how to count again >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this,

```
$("#dialogHolder").dialog({
        maxHeight : 'auto',
        width : 'auto',
        autoOpen : false,
        title : '<span class="logo"></span>',
        modal : true,
        hide : 'blind',
        autoResize : true
    });
```

set a background image for the class `logo` and position it where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will apply to all the dialog in your webapps
Search for this in JQuery UI script.

```
c("<span></span>").addClass("ui-dialog-title").attr("id",e)
```

Change this to

```
c("<img src='[your icon location]'/><span></span>").addClass("ui-dialog-title").attr("id",e)
```